# Removing light switch permanently

Tags: electrical, switch, wire, light

I have a light switch that powers an outlet when it's turned on. I want to remove the switch, connect the wires and make the power in the outlet permanently on. In that case, what am I supposed to do with the ground wire that goes into the switch? The outlet is already grounded so can I just cap off the ground wire that goes into the switch?

Comment: Is there a light in the room that is controlled by another switch? If not this is a code required “switched” outlet for a light. If there is a separate light just nut the wires and put a blank cover on but note what the wiring control for future reference.

Comment: The light in the room is connected to the aforementioned outlet.

Comment: Is it an half always on/half switched? it is much easier in that case.

Comment: **You need a switch in the room in the usual location for a switch, and it needs to turn on a light**.  Obviously you will develop a way to turn on a light, and you and your family will learn how to grope around in the dark to light it. *However, that will not help the EMT who is there to save a family member's life*. First responders and guests need to be able to turn on lights quickly using normal methods (switch in the expected place).

Answer (score 1):

With the light connected to the outlet it would violate code not to have the switch, if you added a ceiling lamp that was switch controlled then this outlet could be wired hot without violating code.

Comment: would a wireless switch (one looking like a normal switch) that controlled room lighting be up to code?

Comment: I believe it would meet code, I have not seen anything forbidding smart switches. And remote switch means (controlled by computers / PLC’s) are how most industrial buildings work. The local switches are an input to the computer or PLC.